# Is the finite dimension of a vector space over the complex numbers half the dimension of the same vector space considered over the reals?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Consider a vector space V with basis ${b_{1},..,b_{n}}$ and complex scalars. This obviously has dimension n. Now consider a space with the same exact set of vectors of V, except with real scalars.

I am thinking the basis of this space would be ${b_{1},...b_{n}, ib_{1}, ...ib_{n}}$ which would have dimension 2n.

Is this correct?

The proof is as follows:
$b_{k}$ and $ib_{k}$ are obviously elements of the space.
With the complex scalars, $b_{k}$ and $ib_{k}$ are dependent.

When considering the same space with real scalars $b_{k}$ and $ib_{k}$ must be independent.
Also, {i$b_{k}$, $b_{1}$, $b_{n}$} must be independent, since otherwise considered as a complex space, {$b_{1}$,..$b_{n}$} would be dependent, which as a basis cannot be.

Is this conclusion and proof correct?

Comment: If you are using the $b_k$ with real multipliers then you have a $n$ dimensional space (over the reals). The basis is still just the $b_k$. With real scalars, you cannot have $i b_k \in \operatorname{sp} \{ b_1,...,b_n \}$.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your question: When you wrote "exact set of vectors" were you referring to the $b_k$ or the space spanned by the $b_k$?

Comment: I meant that if x is an element in the space over C then it is an element of the space over R

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $V$ be the space in question.

Then $b_1,...,b_n$ is a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ **iff** $b_1,...,b_n, i b_1,...,i b_n$ is a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

($\Rightarrow$): If $\sum_k \alpha_k b_k + \sum_k \beta_k (i b_k) = 0$ (with $\alpha_k , \beta_k \in \mathbb{R}$) then
$\sum_k (\alpha_k+i \beta_k) b_k = 0$ and hence $\alpha_k=\beta_k = 0$.
If $v \in V$, then $v = \sum_k \gamma_k b_k$, where $\gamma_k \in \mathbb{C}$.
Hence $v= \sum_k (\text{re } \gamma_k) b_k + \sum_k (\text{im } \gamma_k) ib_k$, and so $b_1,...,b_n, i b_1,...,i b_n$ is a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

($\Leftarrow$): Suppose $\sum_k \gamma_k b_k =0$ where $\gamma_k \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $\sum_k (\text{re } \gamma_k) b_k + \sum_k (\text{im } \gamma_k) ib_k = 0$ and so it follows that $\text{re } \gamma_k = \text{im } \gamma_k = 0$ and so $\gamma_k = 0$.
If $v \in V$ then 
$v=\sum_k \alpha_k b_k + \sum_k \beta_k (i b_k) = 0$ where $\alpha_k , \beta_k \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$v = \sum (\alpha_k + i \beta_k) b_k$ and hence
$b_1,...,b_n$ is a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

It follows that a space has $\dim$ n over $\mathbb C$ **iff** the space has $\dim$ 2n over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Shall I name this "Grazi's complex field theorem of linear spaces" or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @VictorGrazi: :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the answer is that the question is flawed: with real scalar, it won't be "the same space."  For example, suppose, with complex scalars, we have a 2-D space, ${\bf C}^{2}$, with basis
$$
b_{1} = (2 + i3, 0), \; b_{2} = (0, 3 - 2i).
$$
What would be "the same vector space with real scalars"?

Now, if you were thinking of complexification or realification, that's different, and will have a different formulation, depending on what you wanted to ask.

Comment: I don't see how that's a contradiction. In your example b1 and b2 are vectors. It doesn't matter how they're constructed. b1 could be apples and b2 could be bananas. The important thing is that if x and y are elements then ax+by is an element for a and b complex.

Comment: The question is not flawed. If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, then $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ by defining, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v \in V$, $\lambda v = \lambda \cdot v$ where $\cdot$ is multiplication by a scalar in $V$ seen as vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. This construction works for any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ if a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is given.

Comment: The "same vector space with real scalars" would have basis $b_1,b_2,ib_1,ib_2$. (Or the basis $(1,0),(i,0),(0,1),(0,i)$ also works). Every element in your space is a linear combination of those elements with real coefficients.